# How to install QCA Designer in Ubuntud 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

Can someone please help me in installing QCA designer. I need some assistance here with some step by step documentation.

Hoping a reply soon..

Answer (score 2):

In their [download page](http://www.mina.ubc.ca/qcadesigner_downloads), I can see options to download the source file: [QCADesigner-2.0.3-src.tar.gz](http://www.mina.ubc.ca/files/QCA/releases/2.0.3/QCADesigner-2.0.3-1.src.rpm).

After download, uncompress the source file.

First, install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install automake libtool libglib2.0-dev gtk+2.0 libgtk2.0-dev
```

Then configure it with:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/qcadesigner
./configure
```

Edit all `po/*.po` files and add this at the beginning of them:

```
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf8"
```

Then compile and install:

```
make
sudo make install
```